# Cannot convert List<model> to model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, model

Having some issues with my code, its a many to many between 3 tables, im using LINQ to entities, first I group the quote ids then use the id to get the info from each table and try to put it into a viewmodel, im not sure my inhertance is right

There should be one quote with multiple prices from multiple suppliers for multiple items, the item names need to be in the column and the prices below.

Anyway the issue below is

```
Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 
System.Collections.Generic.List<ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes>.Add(ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes)
has some invalid arguments  PurchasingController.cs 48  17  ITAPP`

Error   4   Argument 1: cannot convert from             
System.Collections.Generic.List<ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes>' to 'ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes'  
PurchasingController.cs 48  37  ITAPP`
```

and here is the code

```
var tblQuoting =
    from d in db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers 
    group d by new
    {
        d.QuoteID
    } into g
    select new {
        QuoteID = g.Key
    };

var model = new List<QuoteViewModel>();
foreach (var Quotes in tblQuoting)
{

    var ModelItem = new QuoteViewModel();

    ModelItem.Quote = new List<tblQuotes>();
    ModelItem.Suppliers = new List<tblSuppliers>();
    ModelItem.Items = new List<tblItems>();
    ModelItem.Prices = new List<tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers>();

    //Add the quote info to model
    int QuoteID = Convert.ToInt32(Quotes.QuoteID);
    var Quote = (from d in db.Quotes
                    where d.ID == QuoteID
                    select d).ToList();

    ModelItem.Quote.Add(Quote);

    //add all the suppliers to the quote model
    var Suppliers = (from d in db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Include(t => t.tblSuppliers)
                        where d.QuoteID == QuoteID
                        select d).ToList();
    ModelItem.Suppliers.Add(Suppliers);

    //add the items to the quote model
    var Items = (from d in db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Include(t => t.tblItems)
                        where d.QuoteID == QuoteID
                        select d).ToList();
    ModelItem.Items.Add(Items);

    model.Add(ModelItem);
}
return View("Index", model);
```

this is my model (if its right?)

```
public class QuoteViewModel
{
    public List<tblQuotes> Quote { get; set; }
    public List<tblSuppliers> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public List<tblItems> Items { get; set; }
    public List<tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AddRange` to add sequence of items to list:

```
ModelItem.Quote.AddRange(Quote);
ModelItem.Suppliers.AddRange(Suppliers);
ModelItem.Items.AddRange(Items);
```

Or simply assign lists without initialization (thus you will avoid creating intermediate list and copying items from one list to another):

```
ModelItem.Quote = Quote;
ModelItem.Suppliers = Supplies;
ModelItem.Items = Items;
```

Or even use object initalizer:

```
 var ModelItem = new QuoteViewModel {
      Quote = db.Quotes.Where(q => q.ID == QuoteID).ToList(),
      Suppliers = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Include(t => t.tblSuppliers)
                    .Where(s => s.QuoteID == QuoteID).ToList(),
      Items = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Include(t => t.tblItems)
                .Where(i => i.QuoteID == QuoteID).ToList()
 };
```

Comment: i like the 3rd option, alot shorter code, but im getting the error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ITAPP.Models.tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ITAPP.Models.tblSuppliers>' PurchasingController.cs 38 33 ITAPP

Comment: ive added my model to the original post

Comment: @AlexW that's because you are selecting from database entities from table `tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers` which looks like have type `tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers`. And then you are assigning them to list of `tblSuppliers` type. Same issue was in your original code. Make sure you are selecting correct entities from database

Comment: Yeah i thought that, im not sure how to get each quote into a model, do you see what im trying to do? anyhelp would be much appreciated, im quite confused on how to get this to work

Comment: If you are selecting `tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers` entities from database, then your model's Suppliers property should be of type `List<tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers>`

Comment: ive just updated all my code and have a new error that ive edited and shown above, Thanks

Comment: @AlexW I rolled back your edit (it's not good to change your question - you should ask another one if you have new problem). What type `Quotes.QuoteID` has?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43269/discussion-between-alexw-and-sergey-berezovskiy)